# For what reasons would it be 'bad' to upload big files (10 megs) via a normal file HTML tag on a server?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

For what reasons would it be 'bad' to upload big files (10 megs) via a normal file HTML tag on a server ?
(Of course, to do that, some PHP settings has to be changed)
Maybe it uses too much RAM for the server when downloading, or else ?

Comment: I am sorry for this is a general question, but I just would like to know if it's "bad" or not, and why

Comment: Consider an attacker starts spamming your upload server. Would it be bad to give him the opportunity to attack with larger files?

Comment: Thanks Khez. Any other reasons ?

Comment: RAM use itself is not a problem as PHP stores uploads directly onto disk.

Comment: concurrent users might be a reason too. Larger files require connections to be kept alive longer, which can have adverse effects. "bad" is a very relative term.

Comment: This needs more context.

Comment: Thanks. As this is a functionnality that will be able only for a couple of user (5 max) that are trusted users, the possible problem mentionned won't occure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general reason why this would be "bad".

However, a hosting provider with dozens or hundreds of customers on one server might feel compelled to set the maximum upload size to such a low limit, in order to prevent overloading through many concurrent uploads on many sites.

These uploads have to be temporarily stored somewhere, and twenty concurrent connections uploading a 200MB file each might put a lot of stress on the server.